# Do I need another association in my UML diagram?

Tags: java, arraylist, uml

I have made this simple UML diagram.

[image: Simple UML V2]

I want to have a list of treatments inside class Customer.

My question is if I need another association to make this possible.

Comment: If this is supposed to be a class diagram, then I do not understand why `Treatment` is associated with `Menu` and not with `Customer`. Also, the arrows are inheritance relationships. Why do`Treatment` and `Customer` inherit from `Menu`?

Comment: Hello,

You are right.. I used the wrong arrows. I've updated my UML and added an aggregation.

However I'm still not sure if this is correct.

I appreciate any tips and/or feedback.

Troviç

Comment: Have a look at association classes.

Answer (score 1):

A class diagram describes classes and not objects.  A `TreatmentList` is a `TreatmentList`,  regardless if you look at it from the `Menu` or the `Customer` persepective.

So indeed,  if you want a list of treatment "inside" the class `Customer`, you'll need just to add another association between the classes you want to connect.

Now I wonder if you did not try to design user interface using a class diagram:

- `Main` -> `Menu` -> `List 1` or `List 2` looks terribly like a flow in the user interface, more than a set of related classes.  You don't need this.  And  lass diagrams are not meant for this purpose. If you want to model an UI `Menu`,  you'd model a menu class,  i.e a general class that could instantiate any kind of menus, with a one-to-many association with `MenuAction`. Perhaps  `ShowTreamtmentList` would be a specialization of such an action.
- The `TreatmentList` and `CustomerList` only make sense if these are classes,  i.e. they could be instantiated into one or several objects that each represent a different list.  If, for an association, you'd have a multiplicity of `*` on the side of customer or treatment, you would not need to add a special list/set/bag in the middle.
- You don't need to use an aggregate instead of an association.  [Aggregate are not very uselful and appear to be overused](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67426478/3723423).  Prefer a simple association.