# Database implementation class-diagram

Tags: database, oracle, uml, class-diagram

I created every table in an Oracle database but I don't know how implement the relations between tables[my class-diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeIyS.png) ?

Comment: In RDBMS relationship between tables is implemented via `foreign key` constraint: directly at a table level for 1:1 or 1:n cardinality and using additional table with two foreign keys for N:M cardinality

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Database implementation of a class-diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70046163/database-implementation-of-a-class-diagram) : although it’s another diagram the typical issues with ilplementin a one-to-many association in a database are covered in the answers.

Comment: And this other one, is about specific of the composition (black diamond): https://stackoverflow.com/a/71229243/3723423